# [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have an inventory database to track some equipment which I sometimes loan out.  I have a Device table, and also a DeviceHistory table.  There are two forms which I use to update the Device record, and updates are also recorded in the DeviceHistory table.  Both forms call the same update function.  I am temporarily writing out the sql to try to locate the differences.  When I use formA it results in:

```
insert into QADeviceHistory (DeviceID, Timestamp, StatusID, AuthorID, AssignedToID, History) 
values ( 264, '11/15/2018 9:31:10 AM', 'AVAIL', 'rongray', '', '');
```

and everything works just fine.  However, when I use formB it results in:

```
insert into QADeviceHistory (DeviceID, Timestamp, StatusID, AuthorID, AssignedToID, History) 
values ( 264, '11/15/2018 9:31:45 AM', 'AVAIL', 'rongray', '', '');
```

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint 'QADeviceHistory_pk'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.QADeviceHistory'. /py2/DeviceRecord.asp, line 1393

The primary key for DeviceHistory is DeviceID and Timestamp, and the values I am attempting to enter really are unique.   Oddly enough, the DeviceHistory record DOES get written to the table, so I really don't understand why I am getting the error when using formB but not getting the error when using formA.  I am tempted to just add an on resume next and ignore it but would at least like to understand what's happening.

(Also, this is not new code... it's been around for a few years.  The only recent change is that I had to migrate the database from a Win 2008 server to a Win 2016 server, and both servers are using MS SQL Server 2008.)

Comment: The error is very clear. You tried to insert a record with an existing ID. It doesn't matter at all how old the code is if the *new values* are duplicate, or if a bug in the code results in invalid data.

Comment: As for the core working `/py2/DeviceRecord.asp, line 1393` is *extremely worrying*. A 1400+ long VBScript file that performs data access can easily *hide* errors. VBScript didn't have exceptions making it easy to ignore errors and just keep running. An ingored error could mean that the code tried to add `ID 0` twice for example.

Comment: Another issue is that Classic ASP/VBScript had *half-baked* Unicode support. BSTR strings were Unicode but *ASP* required explicit configurationto work with Unicode.

Comment: In any case, without any code it's not possible to help. If you want to check what the code really does, use SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events to see what SQL queries are actually executed.

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table which might be doing something funky?

Comment: The full DDL of the table `QADeviceHistory` would help here; including constraints. Although you're saying that the Primary key is on `(DeviceID, Timestamp)` I would hazard a guess it's just on `DeviceID`.